# value tree item python tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I use Python with Tkinter, and I have a treeview with several rows.

How to test the value of this expression:

```
self.tree.item(self.tree.selection())['values'][0]
```

For example, I want to verify that the expression above is not empty or null, how shall I do it?

And what means `['values'][0]` in this expression?

Thanks.

Comment: Read [New Mexico Tech Tkinter 8.5 reference on `ttk.Treeview`](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/ttk-Treeview.html) about `ttk.Treeview` methods `.item()` and `.insert()` in the table of `item` options and you'll see `values` is a list of the column values for a row in column order from left to right, so your expression is the value of the 1st columm in the row given by the `iid` of `self.tree.selection()`

Comment: Also, welcome to StackOverflow. You might look at the [help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help) especially the sections on [How to write a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to ask a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Good luck and happy coding!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Update 2020-03-09*: [John Shipman, who developed the documentation for New Mexico Tech, unfortunately passed away in 2019](https://www.nmt.edu/news/2019/nmt_dedicates_shipman_plaque.php), and NMT no longer hosts the material he created. There is an archive [online here](https://anzeljg.github.io/rin2/book2/2405/docs/tkinter/index.html) and a [PDF copy here](http://reu.cct.lsu.edu/documents/Python_Course/tkinter.pdf).

---

For example, reading throught the [New Mexico Tech `ttk.Treeview` docs](https://anzeljg.github.io/rin2/book2/2405/docs/tkinter/ttk-Treeview.html) you can use the following code to create the 3 x 3 treeview below.

```
>>> import Tkinter
>>> import ttk
>>> root = Tk()
>>> root = Tkinter.Tk()
>>> master = Tkinter.Frame(root)
>>> master.pack()
>>> tree = ttk.Treeview(master, columns=['col A','col B','col C'])
>>> tree.pack()
>>> row1 = tree.insert("",index=0,text="row1",values=['A1','B1','C1'])
>>> row1  # 'I001'
>>> row2 = tree.insert("",index=0,text="row2",values=['A2','B2','C2'])
>>> row2  # 'I002'
>>> row3 = tree.insert("",index=0,text="row3",values=['A3','B3','C3'])
>>> row3  # 'I003'
```

[image: treeview_so.png]

Clicking on `row3` highlights that row so that `tree.item.selection()` returns the `iid` of that selected row, *ie*: `I003`. The documentation for [Python `Tkinter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/tkinter.html) and [`ttk`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ttk.html) can be suplimented by the offical [TclTk Documentation of Tk Commands](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TkCmd/contents.htm) and espectially [`ttk::treeview`](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TkCmd/ttk_treeview.htm) in this case, where we read that [`selection`](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TkCmd/ttk_treeview.htm#M47):

> returns the list of selected items

So now we can test the [OP](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5738070/k-doe)'s snippet.

```
>>> tree.selection()  # ('I003',)
>>> tree.item(tree.selection())
# {'image': '',
#  'open': 0,
#  'tags': '',
#  'text': 'row3',
#  'values': [u'A3', u'B3', u'C3']} 
>>> tree.item(tree.selection())['values']  # [u'A3', u'B3', u'C3']
>>> tree.item(tree.selection())['values'][0]  # u'A3'
>>> if tree.item(tree.selection())['values'][0]:
...     # test for zero, empty string or None
...     pass  # do stuff
```

So a combination of reading the documentation, creating a complete example and testing commands in an interactive session should answer your question.

Comment: Thank you, but how do you center the values for each line, please?
In your GUI, if you enlarge the window, the treview is not proportional to the expansion, how to render proportional to the expansion (responsive) ?
Thank you very much.

Comment: @K.Doe can you please read [_What should I do when someone answers my question_ in the help docs](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers), and then consider voting on this answer and deciding whether to accept it or not. Then after reading through the links I provided for New Mexico Tech Tkinter reference, the Python Standard Library and the TclTk Documenation on Tk Commands, consider creating a new question regarding "how to render proportional to the expansion (responsive)?" if you still can not answer it on your own. Good luck!